# Curve whose tangent vector is collinear with normal vector of another curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

A have a question for someone who's an expert in differential geometry. Is there a special name for curves such that a tangent vector of one curve is collinear ( or even equal) to a normal vector of another curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called an *evolute*, while the converse is an *involute*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute