# Special curves- tangent vector of one is collinear with binormal vector of another curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Is there some special name for curves such that a tangent vector of one curve is colinear with a binormal vector of another curve?

Comment: The closest notion I am aware of : "Bertrand pair of curves" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_curve which are 3D curves having common normals...

Comment: I just saw your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3554840 I see you want to generalize form 2D to 3D. By why choosing in 3D the binormal and not the normal ?

Comment: I apologize for not answering your question. Actually, I'm analyzing curves in the Lorentz-Minkowski space, don't know if you are familiar with it. There are some conclusions about Bertrand curves, but in this case curves don't need to be Bertrand curves.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but it seems unlikely these pairs of curves have a name, since they are quite abundant. If $B_\alpha(s)$ is the binormal vector field along any curve $\alpha$, then the curve $\beta(s) = \int B(s)\,ds$ (componentwise integration) is a curve with tangent vector $T_\beta(s) = B_\alpha(s)$.

Note: there is no pair of curves such that the binormal lines on one curve equal tangent lines of the other.

Take two spaces curves $\alpha,\beta\colon I \subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{E}^3$ and let $s$ be a unit speed parameter for $\alpha$. Assume that the binormal lines of $\alpha$ at  $\alpha(s)$ equals the tangent line of $\beta$ at corresponding points $\beta(s)$.

Every point $\beta(s)$ lies on a binormal line of $\alpha$, hence there is a function $\lambda\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ 
  \beta(s) = \alpha(s) + \lambda(s) B_\alpha(s).
$$ 
Deriving and using Frenet gives
$$
  \beta'(s) = T_\alpha(s) + \lambda'(s) B_\alpha(s) - \lambda(s) \tau(s)N_\alpha(s).
$$
Now take the inner product with $T_\alpha(s)$. Since $\beta'(s)$ is parallel with $T_\beta(s) = \pm B_\alpha(s)$, we get $0 = 1$. Contradiction.

Comment: The OP didn't quite mean this, I think. Why does $\beta$ have to lie on the binormal line of $\alpha$? My reading is just that the vectors are themselves linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you for your opservation and comments. I also didn't get it why $\beta$ has to lie on the binormal line of $\alpha$, but even such a special case helps.

Comment: Aha... In hindsight I don't know why I assumed  this. Presumably the comment of Jean Marie on Bertrand curves made me believe this was what the OP asked. I will adjust my answer.